# Count number of observations per day, month and year in R

Tags: r

I have the a dataframe in the following form (its too big to post here entirerly):

```
      listing_id    date    city    type    host_id availability
1   703451  25/03/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
2   703451  20/04/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
3   703451  28/05/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
4   703451  15/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
5   703451  30/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
6   703451  19/08/2013  amsterdam   Entire home/apt 3542621 245
```

and so on...

I would like three new data frames. One counting the number of observations for a particular year (2013,2012, 2011 and so on) another per month (07/2013, 06/2013 and so on) and another per day (28/05/2013, 29/05/2013 and so on). 
I just want to count how many occurances there are per unit of time.

How would I do that?

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table`, this is pretty straightforward:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("listing_id    date    city    type    host_id availability
703451  25/03/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
703451  20/04/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
703451  28/05/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
703451  15/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
703451  30/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
703451  19/08/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245")
dt$date <- as.Date(dt$date, "%d/%m/%Y")

dt[, .N, by=year(date)] 
#    year N
# 1: 2013 6

dt[, .N, by=.(year(date), month(date))] 
#    year month N
# 1: 2013     3 1
# 2: 2013     4 1
# 3: 2013     5 1
# 4: 2013     7 2
# 5: 2013     8 1

dt[, .N, by=date] # or: dt[, .N, by=.(year(date), month(date), day(date)] 
#          date N
# 1: 2013-03-25 1
# 2: 2013-04-20 1
# 3: 2013-05-28 1
# 4: 2013-07-15 1
# 5: 2013-07-30 1
# 6: 2013-08-19 1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can convert the 'date' column to `Date` class, extract the `year` using the `?year` from `library(lubridate)`, get the month-year using `as.yearmon` from `library(zoo)`.  We place the 'dates', 'yr', 'monyr' in a `list`, loop through it (`lapply`), and create the count of occurance column in the original dataset ('df1') using `ave`.  It is better to place the datasets in the `list`.  However, if you insist, we can overload the global environment with multiple objects using `list2env`.

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
dates <- as.Date(df1$date, '%d/%m/%Y')
yr <- year(dates)
monyr <- as.yearmon(dates)
lst <- lapply(list(dates, yr, monyr), function(x) 
       transform(df1, Count=ave(seq_along(x), x, FUN= length)))
names(lst) <- paste0('newdf', seq_along(lst))
list2env(lst, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get your index into Postxct format, then:

`counts <- data.frame(table(as.Date(index(my_data_frame))))`

Change `as.Date` as necessary.

Comment: What about "per day, month and year"?

Comment: The index() function is in the zoo package.

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`, you can do

```
dd %>% group_by(year=year(date)) %>% count()
dd %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date)) %>% count()
dd %>% group_by(year=year(date), month=month(date), day=day(date)) %>% count()
```

Where

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dd <- read.table(text="      listing_id    date    city    type    host_id availability
1   703451  25/03/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
2   703451  20/04/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
3   703451  28/05/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
4   703451  15/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
5   703451  30/07/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245
6   703451  19/08/2013  amsterdam   Entire_home/apt 3542621 245", header=T) %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(date))
```