# R Count number of rows by Date and hour

Tags: r, date, time, count

I have in R a big dataset spanning several days and need to create a new vector which counts the number of rows belonging to each hour of each date, with zeros if the hours in between are not represented (so there will be 24 values in the vector for each day). For example:

```
Date       
29/07/2012 20:00:01
29/07/2012 20:00:02
29/07/2012 20:00:03
29/07/2012 22:01:01
29/07/2012 22:02:01
29/07/2012 22:02:03
30/07/2012 02:05:05
30/07/2012 02:05:06
30/07/2012 12:09:07
30/07/2012 12:10:06
31/07/2012 01:24:36
31/07/2012 01:24:40
```

would give a vector of

```
3,0,3,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2
```

I've found similar things ([Count number of observations per day, month and year in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734043/count-number-of-observations-per-day-month-and-year-in-r) and [R group by date, and summarize the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575785/r-group-by-date-and-summarize-the-values)) but they use `as.Date` as they don't account for hour and I haven't been able to adapt them to work.

How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`.  After converting the 'Date' column datetime class, get the `count` based on the `Date` and the `hour`, grouped by 'Date1', `complete` for any missing sequence

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Date = dmy_hms(Date)) %>% 
    count(Date1 = as.Date(Date), Hour = hour(Date)) %>%
    group_by(Date1) %>% 
    complete(Date1, Hour = min(Hour):24, fill = list(n = 0)) %>%
    arrange(Date1, Hour)
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun. It looks promising but it's not performing quite right. It's missing out most of the hours where there are 0 counts. Currently the output I get shows 15 "N" values instead of the 29 there should be (29 hours between 29/07/2012 20:00 and 31/07/2012 01:00)?

Comment: @Noosentin  Is it  based on `min(Hour):24`